# trigger python script everytime a file is downloaded into a specific folder

Tags: python, directory, zip

I have a specific folder in which I download certain .zip files. I am writing a python script to automate the unzip, upload, and deletion of files from this folder. Is there a way to automatically trigger my python script each time a zip file is downloaded to this folder?

[EDIT] : i am on osx mavericks, sorry for not mentioning this from the start

Comment: Please add more information about you operating system. For example, with Linux you can run a command every minute to automatically call your Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am on Mac OSX Mavericks, my best bet is to use [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) - the most popular python module for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use inotify (e.g. using pyinotify) to get a callback whenever a new file is created. It is not available on Windows though. There *might* be a similar api available, but I don't know if there are python bindings for *that* API.

Comment: Thanks but Pyinotify is not availiable on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of:
Make a cronjob lets say every 1 minute, that launches a script to check the directory in question for any new zip files.
If found it will trigger unziping, upload and deletion.

if you don't want to create a cronjob you can always think about creating a daemon (but why bother)